# Python not able to add two integers thinking they're strings

Tags: python, typeerror

I am trying to add two integers in python yet it seems to think that the variables are a string? Here is a snippet of my code:

```
raiseAmount1 = int
raiseAmount2 = int
while end == False:
    action1 = raw_input(str(Players.player1)[9:] + ", what is your move? (r/c/f):")
    if action1 == 'f':
        Players.player2.score = Players.player2.score + 1
        game().winner = str(Players.player2)[9:]
        end = True
    elif action1 == 'r':
        raiseAmount1 = raw_input("Raise by: ")
        Players.player1.money = Players.player1.money - raiseAmount1
        Table.pot = Table.pot + raiseAmount1
        end = False
```

(Full code here: http://pastebin.com/T6N8gmJk)

And here is the error:

```
Welcome to texas holdem!
You are on round: 0
human, what is your move? (r/c/f):r
Raise by: 80
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "poker.py", line 144, in <module>
        game()
    File "poker.py", line 18, in game
        playGame()
    File "poker.py", line 129, in playGame
        bettingRound()
    File "poker.py", line 96, in bettingRound
        Players.player1.money = Players.player1.money - raiseAmount1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

So the program thinks that either raiseAmount1 or Players.player1.money is a string.

If I convert both variables to an integer using `int()` it continues as normal, but then breaks again at the next line when adding Table.pot to raise amount one. I do the same thing with `int()` but this time it doesn't work.

I don't see how python thinks the variables are a string because all of them are previously defined as integers.

I think the most likely cause that I can think of is that when the program sets `Player.player1 = ai (or human)` it does not carry forward its integer property?

Comment: What do you expect this to do? raiseAmount1 = int

Comment: please read a python tutorial!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`raw_input` returns a string. You need to convert it like this:

`int(raw_input("Raise by: "))`

Also, notice that if the user enters any other character this will raise an error.

You can also just use `input` instead of `raw_input`:

`input("Raise by: ")`

This will, again, raise an error if the user enters any other character.

Comment: or just use input

Comment: Thank you, added!

Answer (score 0):

you need to do an implicit cast of the line, since the method raw_imput returns a string, you are also using variable declaration at the start of your code like if it were c or java, remember that variables in python can change their type in execution time, so a variable that once was a string could be an int at some other point in time.

a valid solution should be:

```
while end == False:
    action1 = raw_input(str(Players.player1)[9:] + ", what is your move? (r/c/f):")
    if action1 == 'f':
        Players.player2.score = Players.player2.score + 1
        game().winner = str(Players.player2)[9:]
        end = True
    elif action1 == 'r':
        raiseAmount1 = raw_input("Raise by: ")
        Players.player1.money = Players.player1.money - raiseAmount1
        Table.pot = Table.pot + int(raiseAmount1)
        end = False
```

You can also use the function input instead of raw_input. I recommend you check out a bit of tutorials to learn how python's variables are assigned, https://www.codecademy.com/ is a very good place to start programming.

Answer (score -1):

```
raiseAmount1 = int
raiseAmount2 = int
```

These 2 lines **do not** guarantee whatsoever that `raiseAmount1` and `raiseAmount2` will be integers everywhere in the program, not even one line below them. Python is not C or Java where you declare a variable to be of type X and it remains that type throughout your program.

`raiseAmount1 = raw_input("Raise by: ")` assigns to `raiseAmount1` the user-inputted string. If you want it to be an integer then you have to call `int` on it: `int(raiseAmount1)`, and be prepared to catch a `ValueError` exception in case the inputted string doesn't represent an integer.

Comment: And the reason for the downvote is?